# Spinner on an ActionBar issue on a Dialog Activity

Tags: android, dialog, android-actionbar

Hi I have an activity that shows a dialog form an standard layout.

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"/>

I was trying to add a simple spinner to the actionbar but I am having issues and error in the line  getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST).

When I change my theme to a common activity it works perfect.

This are the errors showed by the logcat:

```
3114-3114/org.PeteProto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.PeteProto/org.PeteProto.Detail}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.PeteProto.Detail.onCreate(Detail.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: what does the error on that line say

Comment: it does not provide too much information that I can understand. I added a try-catch in that line and the exception object came null.

Comment: you might not understand it but we might

Comment: Logcat shows several errors I am going to add to the questions

Comment: look at line 30 in your Detail class, whatever is there is null

Comment: A `Dialog` themed `Activity` does not have an `ActionBar` so `getActionBar()` will return `null`.

Comment: Thank you. But why the is the reason to have Dialog and Dialog.NoActionBar if there is not action bar in a a dialog? It looks also if you use dialog you will have a label with the name of that activity like a regular action bar

Comment: For convenience probably, both themes disable the `ActionBar`, the only difference between them is that the `Dialog.NoActionBar` also removes the window title.

Comment: Well thank you I faked in design time an action bar